# How can I view the params used to install an already-installed package using Chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

If I already have a package on my system that was installed using `choco install <package> -params "params"`, is there a command I can run to view those params? This is useful, for example, if I need to re-run the full install command later (since I don't normally remember the params I used to install it initially).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a choco command that can help with that currently, no.  For security purposes, those parameters are persisted and encrypted.  There is a non-official utility tool that you can use to do what you want though, you can find this here:

https://github.com/CollinChaffin/DecryptChocoArgs

> Decrypt and display stored Chocolatey package argument files for reference/troubleshooting

Comment: Would it be better to rephrase my question to maybe ask how I can better keep track of the initial parameters I use to install a package (as in, *before* I actually install the package)? Would that have a better (ideally intrinsic) answer?